# Pentaho PDI Date Conversion gives wrong value of month for MMM-yy using Select Values

Tags: datetime, pentaho, kettle, date-conversion, pdi

Hi Im converting String Dates in Pentaho Data Integration to Date

the date appears like Nov-18 which according to Pentaho Date format guide would be

https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/date-field

is MMM-yy so when I use Select Values from Transformation

[My Select Values Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3P0q.png)

So when Running the Transformation the Date comes out as Jan-2018 instead of Nov-18

Why is this Strange Error occurring and How do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These formats for data values are all case sensitive

The format you want is MMM-yy (2 lower case Y), not MMM-YY

Comment: you seem to be right though I thought it was a error with pentaho as the process runs but error was only on single months not multiple months

Comment: lets see if others get similar issue

Comment: You mean the Error was on single digit Months ?

Comment: yes it was it worked perfectly on multi-months with MMM-yy and MMM-YY, MMM-yy works on both generally